# Angular: 2 bugs in saving to local storage

Tags: json, angular, local-storage

I have 2 bugs in methods that save products to local storage (when a user adds them to 'favorites').

The code is part of Angular service, but it can be read without this reference also.

First bug: Sometimes, when a user saves a product to favorites, not one, but multiple products get stored.

Second bug: When I store too many products, I get an error saying that the storage is full (it's full because I parse JSON wrongly, so unwanted additional backslashes are added).

This is the codepan (you can see the result in the console): https://codepen.io/mandy555/pen/dyPVGxj

```
  storage;
  storageKeys;
  x;
  i = 0;
  saveId;
  arr;
  normalArr;
  productInStore;
  productsInStore;
  idsInStore;
  newIds;
  newProducts;
  favorites;

  storageAvailable(type) {

    try {
      this.storage = window[type];
      this.x = '__storage_test__';
      this.storage.setItem('x', this.x);
      this.storage.removeItem('x');
      return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
      return e instanceof DOMException && (
        // everything except Firefox
        e.code === 22 ||
        // Firefox
        e.code === 1014 ||
        // test name field too, because code might not be present
        // everything except Firefox
        e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
        // Firefox
        e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') &&
        // acknowledge QuotaExceededError only if there's something already stored
        (this.storage && this.storage.length !== 0);
    }
  }

  storeFavorite(product = '', productId = '') {

    productId = String(productId);
    this.normalArr = [];

    if (this.storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
      this.storage = window.localStorage;

      if (!this.storage.getItem('favorites_id')) {
        this.saveId = productId;
        this.normalArr.push(product);
      } else {
        this.productsInStore = JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem('favorites_product'));

        if (this.storage.getItem('favorites_id').indexOf(',') === -1) {
          this.arr = [this.storage.getItem('favorites_id')];
          this.normalArr = this.productsInStore;
        } else {
          this.arr = this.storage.getItem('favorites_id').split(',');
          this.normalArr = this.productsInStore;
        }

        if (!this.arr.includes(productId) && productId !== '') {
          this.saveId = this.storage.getItem('favorites_id') + ',' + productId;
          this.normalArr.push(product);
        } else {
          this.saveId = this.storage.getItem('favorites_id');
        }
      }

      this.storage.setItem('favorites_id', this.saveId);
      this.storage.setItem('favorites_product', JSON.stringify(this.normalArr));
    } else {
      this.storage = null;
    }
  }

  deleteFavorite(productId = '') {

    productId = String(productId);
    this.normalArr = [];

    if (this.storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
      this.storage = window.localStorage;

      if (this.storage.getItem('favorites_id') && this.storage.getItem('favorites_product')) {
        this.productsInStore = JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem('favorites_product'));

        if (this.storage.getItem('favorites_id').indexOf(',') === -1) {
          this.storage.clear();
        } else {
          this.idsInStore = this.storage.getItem('favorites_id').split(',');

          this.newIds = this.idsInStore.filter(id => {
            return id !== productId;
          });
          this.newproducts = this.productsInStore.filter(product => {
            return String(product.id) !== productId;
          });

          this.newIds = this.newIds.join();

          this.storage.setItem('favorites_id', JSON.stringify(this.newIds));
          this.storage.setItem('favorites_product', JSON.stringify(this.newproducts));

        }
      }
    } else {
      this.storage = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] and ask about one thing at a time.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, why are you saving "favorites_id" and '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was that I forgot to assign `storage` to local storage. The second solution was to save `x` and not `JSON.stringify(x)` in the local storage, since `x` was already a string. The corrected version is here:
https://codepen.io/mandy555/pen/dyPVGxj